# Проблема в использовании одного объекта разными классами

Tags: java, ооп

У меня есть класс, объект которого должны использовать другие классы. Причем, они должны делать это согласованно, то есть использовать один и тот же объект. Правильно я понимаю, что нужно смотреть в сторону паттерна одиночка? Сейчас я реализую это следующим образом: создаю объект в главном классе(который является точкой входа в программу), а дальше передаю его всем нуждающимся классам. При этом сам отслеживаю, что бы нигде не был создан новый объект этого класса. Правильно я понимаю, что мне надо смотреть в сторону паттерна?
Но у меня есть еще другая и проблема: из-за того что я создаю объект раньше чем его нужно использовать, я создаю его пустым. Есть просто конструктор без параметров и с пустым телом:

```
public Task() {
}
```

У класса Task есть много полей. Покажу на примере трех:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> weights = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<BigInteger> limitSums = new ArrayList<>();
```

Далее, другие классы наполняют этот объект данными через сеттеры. Получается, что нормально использовать этот класс можно только после того как вызваны его сеттеры. Например, есть метод:

```
public void calcLimitRow(int row) {
    BigInteger sum = new BigInteger("0");
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.get(row).size(); i++) {
        if (weights.get(row).get(i) != null && solution.get(i) == 1) {
            sum = sum
                    .add(new BigInteger(weights.get(row).get(i).toString()));
        }
    }
    if (limitSums.size() <= row) {
        limitSums.add(sum);
    } else {
        limitSums.set(row, sum);
    }
}
```

Он использует поля приведенные выше. Получается, нужно вставлять в этот метод проверки, заполнились ли уже поля данными? Я почитал пр паттерн одиночка - он вроде бы не помогает решить эту проблему. Подскажите, может вообще в этом и нет никакой проблемы? Может это нормальная практика и надо просто, как я и сказал выше, вставить в метод проверки? Или все-таки это действительно проблема и есть какой то элегантный способ ее решения? Может стоит обратить внимание на какой-то другой паттерн?

Comment: Вообще-то всё создаётся раньше, чем начинается использование. Что в общем-то логично наверное? Как можно использовать того, чего нет? Вызов сеттеров - это что не использование что ли? В чём проблема-то? Хотите от `if` избавится? Это можно как-нибудь сообразить, если проблема именно в этом.

Comment: Вместо `new BigInteger(weights.get(row).get(i).toString())` можно использовать `BigInteger.valueOf(weights.get(row).get(i))`. По самому вопросу, уточните, кто у вас вызывает `calcLimitRow`, и что он будет делать, если `calcLimitRow` откажется работать? Мне кажется, у вас вычислительная задача, т.е. есть некие данные, из которых путем последовательных преобразований получается ответ. Ооп не нужен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Паттерн Singleton будет полезен, если объект должен быть представлен в единственном экземпляре. При грамотной реализации этого шаблона вы можете быть уверены, что не будет нескольких экземпляров класса (если в вашей программе используется многопоточность, то используйте [double-checked реализацию шаблона](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_checked_locking)).

Судя по описанию вашей проблемы, возможно, стоит пересмотреть саму архитектуру приложения. Класс `Task` не напрашивается на роль синглтона (почему должна быть только одна задача?). Использование данного шаблона больше бы подошло, например, классу менеджер задач `TaskManager`, если он имеется. Далее, если объект класса `Task` может использоваться только после инициализации его полей, то стоит выполнять все необходимые предварительные вычисления и передавать эти значения в конструктор класса, тогда нет необходимости в дополнительных проверках и клиенты данного класса будут уверены, что если объект получен, то он уже полностью инициализирован и готов к работе.

И еще один небольшой совет: программируйте на уровне интерфейсов.

Следующую строку

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> weights = new ArrayList<>();
```

лучше заменить на

```
private List<List<Long>> weights = new ArrayList<>();
```

В этом случае в дальнейшем при необходимости вы можете легко изменить конкретную реализацию, не внося изменений в код клиента (например, понадобится использовать `LinkedList`).

Comment: С TaskManager очень интересная идея, но не понимаю как реализовать( Например, вот как быть в такой ситуации: данные задачи отображаются в JTable(написал свою реализацию модели). Далее, задача целиком меняется, например если я читаю из бд. Слушатель бд не может передать новый объект Task модели потому что у него нет к модели доступа. Я делал так: при чтении в слушателе устанавливал все данные в уже имеющийся объект Task. После модель таблицы работала с тем же самым объектом - данные в таблицы автоматически изменялись. А с TaskManager как можно добиться такой согласованности?

Comment: за ссылку большое спасибо, почитаю на досуге. А про интерфейсы недавно прочитал, да все никак руки не доходят поменять во всех объявлениях ссылок ArrayList на List :)

Comment: @АлександрЕлизаров, так вам и нет необходимости предоставлять доступ классу, считывающему данные из БД, к модели. Модель просто должна уметь хранить данные. Необходимо создать некий контроллер (тот же `TaskManager`), который будет передавать модели изменившиеся данные в нужный момент и вызывать метод обновления вашего представления `JTable`. Этот контроллер и будет взаимодействовать с слушателем БД и другими классами при необходимости. Получается классическая реализация MVC.

Comment: То есть получается, при чтении задачи я смогу создать новый объект Task. А TaskManager поможет передать его в мою реализацию AbstarctTableModel?

Comment: Да, это было бы логично. Новые данные = новая задача.

Comment: спасибо большое! Вы задали мне очень интересное направление, буду разбираться.

Comment: а правильно я понял что TaskManager это будет контроллер, а Task - модель?

Answer (score 2):

Предположу автора коробят вот эти проверки:

```
if (limitSums.size() <= row) {
    limitSums.add(sum);
} else {
    limitSums.set(row, sum);
}
```

Которые приходится выполнять при каждой попытке сохранить что-то в свои массивы.
Есть несколько вариантов. И выбор пути в первую очередь зависит от того, как задаются размерности массивов.
В простейшем случае, если размерности фиксированы, то проще всего инициализировать массивы в конструкторе.

```
public Task(int n, int m) {
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> weights = new ArrayList<>(n);
    private ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<>(n);
    private ArrayList<BigInteger> limitSums = new ArrayList<>(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        weights.add(new ArrayList<>(m));
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            weights.get(i).add(null); // weights.get(i).add(0);
        }
        solution.add(null); // или solution.add(0);
        ...
    }
}
```

Так все массивы будут заполнены какими-то начальными значениями перед использованием. Можно сразу же делать `limitSums.set(row, sum);`

Singleton, если что, не накладывает каких-то особых условий на конструктор, вроде того, что он должен быть пустым. Как надо, так и конструируйте свой синглетон.